# hasIdentity method not working in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am doing an authentication module using `Zend_Auth` in Zend Framework. After successful authentication I am storing users data using `getStorage()`;

Example :

In method `_process` I have written like this :

```
if ($result->isValid()) {                        
    $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();             
    $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
    return true;
}
```

`print_r($user)` showing the result :

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [username] => admin [password] => cb3aefbdffbc81588f3d43c394428b16d4346b44 [salt] => ce8d96d579d389e783f95b3772785783ea1a9854 [role] => administrator [date_created] => 2012-12-29 11:04:40)
```

Now, I want to display `Logout` link if user successfully logged in.

`LoggedInAs.php`

```
    class Zend_View_Helper_LoggedInAs extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function loggedInAs() {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $username = $auth->getIdentity()->username;
            $logoutUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller' => 'auth',
                'action' => 'logout'), null, true);
            return 'Welcome ' . $username . '. <a href="' . $logoutUrl . '">Logout</a>';
        }

        $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action = $request->getActionName();
        if ($controller == 'auth' && $action == 'index') {
            return '';
        }
        $loginUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'index'));
        return '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login</a>';
    }

}
```

But its not calling the method `hasIdentity` thats why its not going to the `if` block and

`print_r($auth)` showing output like this:

`Zend_Auth Object ( [_storage:protected] => )`

`Bootstrap.php`

```
protected function _initSession() {
    Zend_Session::start();
    if (!Zend_Registry::isRegistered('session')) {
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('userIdentity');
        Zend_Registry::set('session', $session);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if user is actually being written to the auth storage. after authe->getstorage()->write on the next line var_dump the contents of $auth->getSTorage()->read();

Comment: @Ali : Yes its showing the result i.e. username, password etc... means its properly written to auth storage.

Comment: The LoggedInAs.php is that a generic function I mean whats the whole file code

Comment: @Ali : I have modified the post...plz check it

Comment: @Ali : That page is mainly for providing `login` and `logout` link

Comment: @Ali : I retrieve the `Zend_Auth` object and the test if a user is logged in using `hasIdentity()`. If the user is logged in, then I use `getIdentity()` to retrieve the data that I loaded earlier.

Comment: Hmmmm it shoudl be ok - lets take a look at your bootstrap

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21858/discussion-between-ultimate-and-ali)

Answer (score 0):

have you added session`$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();` to the action where you are writing `$auth->getStorage()->write($user);`,it should be the first line probably

Example #1 Modifying the Session Namespace

Zend_Auth_Storage_Session uses a session namespace of 'Zend_Auth'. This namespace may be overridden by passing a different value to the constructor of Zend_Auth_Storage_Session, and this value is internally passed along to the constructor of Zend_Session_Namespace. This should occur before authentication is attempted, since Zend_Auth::authenticate() performs the automatic storage of the identity.

```
// Use 'someNamespace' instead of 'Zend_Auth'
$auth->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('userIdentity'));
$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html

Comment: can you post your Bootstrap.php

Comment: I modified the question plz check

Comment: Zend_Auth_Storage_Session uses a session namespace of 'Zend_Auth'. This namespace may be overridden by passing a different value to the constructor of Zend_Auth_Storage_Session, and this value is internally passed along to the constructor of Zend_Session_Namespace. This should occur before authentication is attempted, since Zend_Auth::authenticate() performs the automatic storage of the identity.please refer to #Example 1 http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html